# Finding the characteristic function of $E[e^{iuXY}]$, given X, Y are standard normal, $Cov(X, Y) = 0$

Tags: conditional-probability, characteristic-functions

I'm trying to understand the solution to this question:

Suppose that $(X, Y)$ is a normally distributed random vector with
$X \sim N(0, 1)$, $Y \sim N(0, 1)$, $\text{Cov}(X, Y) = 0$.

Determine the characteristic function $\phi_{XY}(u) = E(e^{iuXY})$ of the product $XY$ for all $u \in \mathbb{R}$.

Hint: Use conditional expectations.

Given solution:

$\phi (u) = \mathbb{E}(\mathbb{E}(e^{iuXY}|Y)) = \mathbb{E}(e^{-\frac{u^2Y^2}{2}}) = \large\int^\infty_{-\infty}e^{-\frac{u^2x^2}{2}}\frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}}e^{-\frac{x^2}{2}}dx$

I don't understand how $\mathbb{E}(e^{-\frac{u^2Y^2}{2}})$ is obtained, using the tower property, is this correct:

$\mathbb{E}(\mathbb{E}(e^{iuXY}|Y)) = \mathbb{E}(\mathbb{E}(e^{iuX}|Y)\cdot Y)$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When $X$ is standard normal, then it has a [characteristic function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Characteristic_function_(probability_theory)#Examples) of: $$\begin{align}\phi_X(t)&=\mathsf E(\mathrm e^{itX})\\&={\mathrm e^{-t^{2}/2}}\end{align}$$

When also, $X,Y$ are independent, $\mathsf E(\mathrm e^{iuXY}\mid Y)=\phi_X(uY).$

So, the application of the *tower property* gives us:

$$\begin{align}\mathsf E(\mathrm e^{iuXY}) &=\mathsf E(\mathsf E(\mathrm e^{iuXY}\mid Y))\\[1ex]&=\mathsf E(\phi_X(uY))\\[1ex]&=\mathsf E(\mathrm e^{-u^2Y^2/2})\end{align}$$

Comment: Very clear thank you!